# $.ajax is redirecting when not wanted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, parameters

I am very new to ajax, today mostly. I have a couple HTML tables where a user can change information in them and it updates the database without having to reload the page, it worked perfectly the first time with this...

Just for explanation sake, my url when this is called is `www.example.com/customers.php?action=viewAll`

```
/************ Update Job Status ************/
$('.update-job-status').on('change', function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).parent().children('#id').val();

    var formData = "id="+id+"&status="+status;

    $.ajax({ // Start the PHP submission
                url : "/resources/submit.php?action=updateJobStatus",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {    //data - response from server
                    $('.notification-success').css('display', 'block').append('Status was updated!');
                    $('.notification-success').fadeOut(2000, function(){
                        $(this).empty();
                    });
                }
            });
});
```

The AJAX returns and keeps us on the same page (`www.example.com/jobs.php?action=viewAll`)

Now I try to call AJAX to perform a different operation on the table...

```
/************ Delete Job ************/
$('.delete-job').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().children('#id').val();
    var formData = "id="+id;

    $.ajax({ // Start the PHP submission
                url : "/resources/submit.php?action=deleteJob",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {    //data - response from server

                }

            });
});
```

Here the AJAX returns us to just `jobs.php`. Why are all the $_GET parameters being truncated? I think that is the case because the URL bar says `.../jobs.php?` (it still has the question mark)

Any ideas on why it is not maintaining it's page?

Comment: Is the button/element that `.delete-job` is referring to a `submit` or `button` element with no `type` attribute? I'm assuming what is happening is that the form is being submitted. A simple test may be to simply put `return false` after your AJAX call.

Comment: Yes it is a button, with no type. `<button class="btn delete-job">Delete</button>`

Comment: Add `type="button"` to the element and it'll solve the problem. By default, a `button` with no type in a `form` automatically submits the enclosing `form`.

Comment: When you use POST you don't put `?` followed by param in URL. You're mixing GET and POST in a way that will not work well.

Comment: @developerwjk what are the consequences of doing it that way?

Comment: Most likely the ones you put in the url rather than the data section will be dropped when using POST.

Comment: @developerwjk's suggestion is also good to take note of.

Comment: I have a submit.php that has if catches in it for the $_GET params, so if the contact form is submitted, it would be directed to. submit.php?action=contactForm. Once there, I call on my other controllers to do the actual work. I just did not want a contact_form.php, signIn.php, *.php. This is not good I take it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with sending url parameters together with a POST request as long as you do not send data in an url, that should be in a POST request (like hidden fields). 
Your method is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `button` element without a `type` attribute is treated like a `submit` element inside of a `form`. What is happening is on click, your AJAX is being submitted, but so is the form, which is thus reloading your page.

A simple fix is to make your button have a type, like:

```
<button type="button" class="delete-job">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your whole page is reloading, it might be that the default action of your 'delete-job' element is triggering. Try to change this bit of code:

```
$('.delete-job').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

the rest of your code...
```

This will prevent the default action of your element from executing.